# status update in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a admin login where the admin has to approve the student,I have used a toggle button for approval option, when clicked on the toggle button the value of status in database as to change from 1 to 0? How do I do this? Even if there are ways for it to work with normal buttons would also be helpful.Thank You.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.noConflict();
            fill_datatable();
    
    
            function fill_datatable(collegeID = '') {
                var table = $('.user_datatable1').DataTable({
                        order: [
                            [0, 'desc']
                        ],
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        ajax: {
                            url: "{{ route('alumni.datatable1') }}",
                            data: {
                                collegeID: collegeID
                            }
    
                        },
                        columns: [{
                                data: 'id',
                                name: 'id'
                            },
    
                            {
                                data: 'name',
                                name: 'name'
                            },
    
                            {
                                data: 'status',
                                name: 'status',
    
    
                                mRender: function(data) {
   return  '<input data-id="{{$colleges->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Approved" data-off="Pending" {{ $colleges->status ? "checked" : "" }}>'

    
                                }
                                
                        },
    
                        {
                            data: 'action',
                            name: 'action',
                            orderable: false,
                            searchable: false
                        },
    
                    ]
                });
        }
    
    
        });
    
       
    </script>

      <script>
                            $(function() {
                                $(".toggle-class").change (function() {
                                  
                                var status = $(this).prop("checked")== true ? 0 : 1;
                                var id = $(this).data("id");
                                $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "json",
                                url: "/changeStatus",
                                data: {"status": status, "id": id},
                                success: function(data) {
                                console.log("Success")
                                }
                                });
                                });
                                });
              

      

    
                                </script>
```

Route

```
    Route::get('changeStatus', [AdminAuthController::class, 'changeStatus'])->name('changeStatus');
```

Controller

```
   public function changeStatus(Request $request,$regno)
    {
        $colleges = College::find($regno);
        $colleges->status = $request->status;
        $colleges->save();
        return back();
    }
```

Comment: you do not need too get the status in the request.  All what you need is to toggle the status: $colleges->status = !$colleges->status;

Comment: but I do need to update my status value in the database.

Comment: yes, your code should work fine just update it to be as I mentioned above. : $colleges->status = !$colleges->status; then as you did call $colleges->save();. This is will be fine

Comment: The thing is the function doesn't get called with the button inside the datatable.. bt it works when i put the button outside the table and try.

Comment: try change this "$(".toggle-class").change (function() " to $(".toggle-class").on('change', (function()

Comment: Thank you for your time but nope.. no changes :(

Comment: The function did work but I'm getting--( jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/changeStatus?status=0&id=3 500 (Internal Server Error)) please let me know what is wrong..

Comment: you need to show the exception. use debug mode to show the whole exception

Comment: The error was about the jquery script tag, I had called bootstrap tags before jquery tags. Jquery script tag must be called first that's why it was not working. Thanks alot for replying. Now its working.